# python socket OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python, sockets

So I've been making a socket filetransfer script with a client and a server. The server has files that the client can request here is the code.

```
#server.py
import socket
import os
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5000
#defining the stuff we want to use
#all the files you can download are stored here
def main():
    file_folder = '/home/lario/Desktop/pyprojects/networking/filetransfer/files/'

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    print('Server started on {}:{}'.format(host, str(port)))
    s.listen(5)
    sentace = 'We have these files for you to download: '
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('[*] Got a connection from {}'.format(addr))
        loop(file_folder, sentace, conn, s, os.listdir(file_folder))
        print('[*] File transfer with {} has been succesfull')
    s.close()

def loop(file_folder, sentace, conn, socket, existing_files):
    #sends which files we have to download for the client
    conn.send(sentace.encode('utf-8') + str(existing_files).encode('utf-8'))
    #gets response which one he wants to download
    data = socket.recv(4096)
    #gets path of the file
    file_place = file_folder + data.decode('utf-8')
    #checks if file exists
    if os.path.isfile(file_place):
        #asks if he wants to download it
        succes = '[+] The file exists, it has {} still wish to download?'.format(os.path.getsize(file_place)).encode('utf-8')
        conn.send(succes)
        data = socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
        #if response is yes send him the file
        if data.lower() == 'y':
            with open(file_place, 'rb') as f:
                file_data = f.read(4096)
                conn.send(file_data)
        else:
            pass


    else:
        succes = '[-] The file doesn\'t exist. Try again'
        conn.send(succes.encode('utf-8'))
        loop(file_folder, sentace, conn, socket, existing_file)


#client.py
import socket
def main():
    ip = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5000
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((ip, port))
    print('[*] Connected to server')
    data = s.recv(1024)
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    file_down = input('-->')
    s.send(file_down.encode('utf-8'))
    data = s.recv(4096)
    if data[1] == '+':
        data = s.recv(4096)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        choice = input("Y/N").lower()
        if choice == 'y':
            s.send(choice.encode('utf-8'))
            prefix = input('What kind of prefix do you want for your files: ')
            with open(str(prefix + file_down), 'wb') as f:
                data = s.recv(4096)
                f.write(data)
        elif choice == 'n':
            s.send(choice.encode('utf-8'))
            print('Well, see you next time.')
        else:
            s.send(choice.encode('utf-8'))
            print('Not a valid input.')

    else:
        print('File doesn\'t exist.')


main()
```

And this is the output.

```
#server
Server started on 127.0.0.1:5000
[*] Got a connection from ('127.0.0.1', 47170)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "server.py", line 17, in main
    loop(file_folder, sentace, conn, s, os.listdir(file_folder))
  File "server.py", line 25, in loop
    data = socket.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

#client
[*] Connected to server
We have these files for you to download: ['syria.txt', 'eye.jpg', 'kim-jong.jpg']
-->
```

You will see I've got string in variables, I did it that way because you can't encode strings like this.

```
'this is a string'.encode('utf-8')
```

The client should choose a file with a prefix to it and it should write the file into anotherfile.

Answer (score 3):

There are two sockets here: The first is the one called `s` in your server `main`. This is a *listening* socket and it's the one you use to `accept` new connections. The `accept` call returns the other socket (which you named `conn`).

The `conn` socket is connected to your peer, and you can both `send` to and `recv` from the peer with it. The `s` socket is *not* connected, and you can neither `send` nor `recv` on it. So there's no reason for you to even pass `s` to your `loop` function. The only significant things you can do with `s` at this point are to `close` it, or `accept` more connections on it.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, i understand it now and i'm going to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the updated code. conn needs to be used instead of socket.

```
#server.py
import socket
import os
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5002
#defining the stuff we want to use
#all the files you can download are stored here
def main():
    file_folder = '<Path To Directory>'

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    print('Server started on {}:{}'.format(host, str(port)))
    s.listen(5)
    sentace = 'We have these files for you to download: '
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('[*] Got a connection from {}'.format(addr))
        loop(file_folder, sentace, conn, s, os.listdir(file_folder))
        print('[*] File transfer with {} has been succesfull')
    s.close()

def loop(file_folder, sentace, conn, socket, existing_files):
    #sends which files we have to download for the client
    conn.send(sentace.encode('utf-8') + str(existing_files).encode('utf-8'))
    #gets response which one he wants to download
    data = conn.recv(100000)
    #gets path of the file
    file_place = file_folder + data.decode('utf-8')
    #checks if file exists
    if os.path.isfile(file_place):
        #asks if he wants to download it
        succes = '[+] The file exists, it has {} still wish to download?'.format(os.path.getsize(file_place)).encode('utf-8')
        conn.send(succes)
        print ("CheckPoint 1 in Server")
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        #if response is yes send him the file
        if data.lower() == 'y':
            with open(file_place, 'rb') as f:
                file_data = f.read(4096)
                conn.send(file_data)
        else:
            pass


    else:
        succes = '[-] The file doesn\'t exist, Try again'
        conn.send(succes.encode('utf-8'))
        loop(file_folder, sentace, conn, socket, existing_file)

main()
```

**Client.py**

```
#client.py
import socket
def main():
    ip = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5002
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((ip, port))
    print('[*] Connected to server')
    data = s.recv(100000)
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
    file_down = input('-->')
    s.send(file_down.encode('utf-8'))
    data = s.recv(4096)
    print (data)
    if data[1] == '+':
        data = s.recv(4096)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        print("Reached here in Client 1")
        choice = input("Y/N").lower()
        if choice == 'y':
            s.send(choice)
            prefix = input('What kind of prefix do you want for your files: ')
            with open(str(prefix + file_down), 'wb') as f:
                data = s.recv(4096)
                f.write(data)
        elif choice == 'n':
            s.send(choice.encode('utf-8'))
            print('Well, see you next time.')
        else:
            s.send(choice.encode('utf-8'))
            print('Not a valid input.')

    else:
        print('File doesn\'t exist.')


main()
```

**Output on Client Side**

```
We have these files for you to download: ['pDiffCompare.py', 'lib', 'g.jar']
-->'pDiffCompare.py'
[+] The file exists, it has 2296 still wish to download?
y
```

**Output on Server Side**

```
Server started on 127.0.0.1:5002
[*] Got a connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38702)
CheckPoint 1 in Server
[*] File transfer with {} has been succesfull
```

Comment: Okay thank you very much, my script is still a little bit buggy but i'm going to fix it right now.

Comment: Yes. Few issues were there but without proper data and requirement, was not able to solve.